# Why does ANT javac task recompile my .java again and again

Tags: ant, javac, recompile

> The source and destination directory will be recursively scanned for
>   Java source files to compile. Only Java files that have no
>   corresponding .class file or where the class file is older than the
>   .java file will be compiled.

The above is from [javac Task, ANT Apache](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html). But I really don't see why in my case .java is recompiled again and again.

My working directory is .../trunk

My source (.java) is located at trunk/src

My target (.class) is located at trunk/bin

My .java files use default package, namely, no package declaration.

The javac task is used this way in my build.xml

```
<javac srcdir="${src}"
   destdir="${bin}"
   includeantruntime="false">
  <classpath>
<pathelement location="${bin}"/>    
<pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
  </classpath>
</javac>
```

where I have defined

```
<property name="src"    value="src"/>
<property name="bin"    value="bin/"/>
```

It seems everything is ok, but each time I run ANT, it recompiles the .java files. Really strange! Anyone would like to tell me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I got the answer. Sorry I did not tell all the story above. Actually, I have an antlr lexer/parser generation before the "javac" part. And for that, I should have added the "-make" option so that the lexer and parser will not be generated again with a more recent timestamp.  (from [Use ANT for ANTLR3](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/How+to+use+ant+with+ANTLR3#HowtouseantwithANTLR3-AfirstexampleusingtheJavatask)

> The ANLTR3 command-line option "-make" only generates new files in
>   case they are older than the grammar. This behaviour might have an
>   effect on dependent tasks like "compile", which could result in
>   nothing to be processed because it is up to date.